# Spark Streaming reading from local file gives NullPointerException

Tags: apache-spark, nullpointerexception, spark-streaming

Using Spark 2.2.0 on OS X High Sierra. I'm running a Spark Streaming application to read a local file:

```
val lines = ssc.textFileStream("file:///Users/userName/Documents/Notes/MoreNotes/sampleFile")
    lines.print()
```

This gives me

```
org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FileInputDStream logWarning - Error finding new files
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef$.length$extension(ArrayOps.scala:192)
```

The file exists, and I am able to read it using SparkContext (sc) from spark-shell on the terminal. For some reason going through the Intellij application and Spark Streaming is not working. Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: how are you running it ? You should bundle jar and then run from shell or from intellij, you should remote deploy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the doc comments of `textFileStream`:

> Create an input stream that monitors a Hadoop-compatible filesystem
>       for new files and reads them as text files (using key as LongWritable, value
>       as Text and input format as TextInputFormat). Files must be written to the
>       monitored directory by "moving" them from another location within the same
>       file system. File names starting with . are ignored.
>
> @param directory HDFS directory to monitor for new file

So, the method expects the path to a **directory** in the parameter.

So I believe this should avoid that error:

```
ssc.textFileStream("file:///Users/userName/Documents/Notes/MoreNotes/")
```

Comment: The NullPointer error is gone but it isn't picking up the file or printing the contents (with lines.print()). it just gives this:
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1521058915000 ms
-------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1521058920000 ms
-------------------------------------------

Comment: Turns out it only picks up new files that are landed, not even files that are moved or renamed.

Answer (score 0):

Spark streaming will not read old files, so first run the `spark-submit` command and then create the local file in the specified directory.  Make sure in the `spark-submit` command, you give only directory name and not the file name.  Below is a sample command.  Here, I am passing the directory name through the spark command as my first parameter.  You can specify this path in your Scala program as well.

```
spark-submit --class com.spark.streaming.streamingexample.HdfsWordCount --jars /home/cloudera/pramod/kafka_2.12-1.0.1/libs/kafka-clients-1.0.1.jar--master local[4] /home/cloudera/pramod/streamingexample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /pramod/hdfswordcount.txt
```